# Get displayed text for an input element

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, selenium, angular-material

My website is using Angular Material which is changing the format of the text entered in my type='time' input field. I'd like to be able to assert against this text but none of the methods I can find for getting it are providing the actual text displayed.

I've tried the following element properties: value, valueAsDate, textContent, innerHTML.

I also tried jqlite's val() method.

Here's a codepen demonstrating my issue: https://codepen.io/carlins/pen/JJNJab

```
//displayed text is 02:57 PM
document.querySelector('input').value         // 14:57:00.000
document.querySelector('input').valueAsDate   // 1970-01-01T14:57:00.000Z
document.querySelector('input').textContent   // empty
document.querySelector('input').innerHTML     // empty
angular.element(document).find('input').val() // 14:57:00.000
```

Comment: what is it currently and whats your expected?

Comment: Is the INPUT box of type 'date'?

Comment: @alphapilgrim The expected value is what's show on the first line of code block

Comment: @rxgx the input box is of type 'time'

Comment: @carlin.scott did you solve the problem

Comment: @user8175473 not really, no. I'm making due with not verifying the format text and just using the value.

Answer (score 0):

You should not get from Element but just play with data, if you need to display in view you can use filter date like 

`{{time | date:'h:mm a'}}`

If you need to get value in Javascript, Just play with dateformat with `time` variable.

Comment: Is there a way to reference the date format that's being used by the input element already? I'd be ok with asking angular for what should be there but I'm not comfortable with telling angular the date format as well. That would put my test on shaky ground.

Comment: Easiest way to play with `date` in Javascript is using `moment`, but it have overkill size.
You may use your own function, like to get time with 
`new Date().toTimeString().split(' ')[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Your input has a datetime value so you get datetime when you want to get input value. In angular you can use date filter to get date string as you wish. I have tried works [here](https://codepen.io/hasanB/pen/GEmMXj)

Reference for date filters: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

```
$scope.timeInnerHTML = function(){
      return $scope.time;
 }

"{{timeInnerHTML() | date:'@h:mma'}}"
```